# Left justifying figure captions

Tags: captions

I would like to align the left side of text together instead of continuing blow Fig. as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Undesired justification of text in caption]

What I would really like is something similar to this:

[image: Desired justification of text in caption]

I'm very sorry but I haven't been able to figure out what to search for to find this feature. Can you please assist me? Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which document class are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that. "new-aiaa", a template for AIAA papers.

Comment: @MattGalles If you like my answer check tick green near my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I can get better now, I cleaned up some code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\centering
\caption{\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna.}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might also include [singlelinecheck=off] for short captions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `\textbf` or `\bfseries` instead of `\bf` as the latter is deprecated? If the text of all the captions in the docment should be bold, one can instead add `\captionsetup{font=bf}` to the preamble.

Comment: It is the default behavior of the KOMA-Script classes. So you can remove packages `floatrow` and `caption` (and `\capitonsetup`). With an uptodate KOMA-Script version you will get an error because of the old font command `\bf`. To change the font of the caption use `\addtokomafont{caption}{\bfseries}` and `\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}`.

Comment: "\captionsetup{format=hang}" was exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Comment: @MattGalles If the answer is ok for you, then accept it as correct by clicking in the tick on its left

Comment: @leandriis, @esdd You're probably right. I use only `\ textbf {}` for bold. I had last night the battery of my unloading laptop and I had to hurry. Now I change the code I have a few minutes available.